# Is it possible to group things as an object but keep materials?

Tags: modeling

I have this model:

[image]

Ideally, everything would be kept in one object, but I know if I Ctrl+J everything, it'll switch the materials to the dominant one. How can I fix this?

Comment: Ctrl+J should keep the same materials. If it doesn't then it's a bug and should be reported.

Comment: While joining shouldn't change the materials [this question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/516/935) provides a couple of approaches to applying multiple materials.

Comment: @user3423509, it would be useful in trying to understand your issue if you would post a ~.blend file to a site like [Blend-Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/).